# Passing a String from ClickListener

Tags: java, android, string, listview, onitemclicklistener

In my activity, I have a `HorizontalScrollView` with nine `TextViews` and below I have a `ListView`. If I click on one of the nine `TextViews` the list will refresh and shows some data which is stored in my DB and has the same value like the `TextView` (this works without any problems).

Now I click on one ListItem and a new activity opens.

Here I want that the value from the `TextView` will send as well to the new `Activity`.

Here is some part of my code:

```
dataSource = new ArrayList<>();

lvWP.setAdapter(new WPAdapter(this, dataSource));
 
horiView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horiView );
    lvWP.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object element = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

            if (element instanceof Workpackage){
                Workpakage workpackage= (Workpakage ) element;

                Intent wp = new Intent(ProjektOverview.this, WorkpackageDetail.class);

                String projekt = tvProjectTitle.getText().toString();

                wp.putExtra(WorkpackageDetail.WP_KEY, workpackage.getId());
                wp.putExtra("DEPARTMENT", department);  //THIS SHOULD BE THE STRING FROM tvWKA
                wp.putExtra("PROJECTNAME", project);

                startActivity(wp);
            }
        }
    });

// HERE I CLICK ON ONE TEXTVIEW FROM THE HORIZONTALSCROLLVIEW 
tvWKA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String department= "WKA";  // THIS STRING I WANT TO SEND TO MY LISTVIEW ONCLICKLISTENER

        String project= tvProjectTitle.getText().toString();
        refreshList(department, projekt);
    }
});

public void refreshList(String department, String project) {
    dataSource.clear();
    dataSource.addAll(WorkpackageDB.getInstance(ProjectOverview.this).readAllAP(department, projekt));
    lvWP.invalidateViews();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make *department* a field of your Activity class? That way, you can access it in onItemClick()

Comment: Because this is to easy :) No serious, thanks, never thought about such an easy way .. just tried it and it worked fine .. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a global variable like `selectedDepartment` in your `Activity` class which can be populated when you click your `TextView`.

```
private String selectedDepartment; 

tvWKA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectedDepartment = "WKA";  
        String project = tvProjectTitle.getText().toString();
        refreshList(department, projekt);
    }
});
```

Then you can add this as an extra while passing intent to another activity.

```
wp.putExtra(WorkpackageDetail.WP_KEY, workpackage.getId());
wp.putExtra("DEPARTMENT", selectedDepartment); // Here 
wp.putExtra("PROJECTNAME", project);
```

Hope that helps!